# react diffing with anonymous component in tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and was looking at three common patters used to share functionality, namely HOCs, render props, and hooks. For a simple button that counts how many times it was clicked I came up with the following to share with counter functionality:

```
// HOC implementation
export const withCounter = Component => props => {
  const [count, updateCount] = useState(0);
  return <Component count={count} increment={() => updateCount(count + 1)} {...props} />;
};

// Render Prop implementation
export const Counter = props => {
  const [count, updateCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => {
    updateCount(count + 1);
  };
  return props.render(count, increment);
};

// Hook implementation
export const useCounter = (initialCount = 0) => {
  const [count, increment] = useState(initialCount);
  const updateCount = () => {
    increment(count + 1);
  };
  return [count, updateCount];
};
```

Then in react dev tools under the components I noticed they all looked different.

Hocs showed as: anonymous -> button1

Render Props showed as: Counter -> button2

Hooks showed as: button3

Reading about react diffing it says if components are not equal it unmounts completely. My questions are the following: Since the Hoc implementation shows as anonymous does this mean it will always get unmounted and thus should be avoided for performance reasons and only used in cases where this is desirable such as authentication, etc, ? The hook implementation has fewer branches on tree, does this mean we should always favor hooks when possible? And lastly, if anonymous causes unmounts I noticed when working with default exports:

```
export default () => component
```

shows as anonymous in the tree, does this mean we should export default like this:

```
const Component = () => component
export default Component
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the Hoc implementation shows as anonymous does this mean it will always get unmounted and thus should be avoided for performance reasons and only used in cases where this is desirable such as authentication, etc, ?

The fact that the HOC generates an intermediate Component that gets displayed as `anonymous` in the React Dev Tools has nothing do with the life-cycle of that Component. That Component will get unmounted for the exact same reasons that a normal component gets unmounted (if its key changes or if one of its ancestors is unmounted)

If you implemented your HOC like this:

```
export const withCounter = Component => function WithCounter(props) {
  const [count, updateCount] = useState(0);
  return <Component count={count} increment={() => updateCount(count + 1)} {...props} />;
};
```

then you would still see an intermediate component in the React Dev Tools, but with this implementation it wouldn't be anonymous. You could also implement it like this if you wanted to get fancier:

```
export const withCounter = Component => {
  const enhancedComponent = props => {
    const [count, updateCount] = useState(0);
    return <Component count={count} increment={() => updateCount(count + 1)} {...props} />;
  };
  enhancedComponent.name = `WithCounter(${Component.displayName || Component.name})`;
  return enhancedComponent;
}
```

> The hook implementation has fewer branches on tree, does this mean we should always favor hooks when possible?

I think that there are plenty of reasons for favoring hooks over HOCs whenever possible... Perhaps one of them is performance... After all using hooks you get a flatter React tree. However, the main reason why I no longer use HOCs is because hooks are a lot easier to compose and to re-use.

> And lastly, if anonymous causes unmounts

It doesn't.

> I noticed when working with default exports...

That's because in the second case [babel transforms your anonymous function into a named function](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwMIgLYAdwFMywLwzoBOI6EMeAfDABQBQAkADwAmAlgG4zhIA2bwANZ4A3sVIQAdD35CAvpTEkyk4AAs2vFkRxymAenYdKdAJRA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=). That doesn't have any impact on performance... However, I do think that it's very useful to easily identify/search my components with the React dev tools.